# I have my code running on jsfiddle, but why can't on local computer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title said,
this is my code running on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/paopaomj/zgGpN/

and I copy all the code on my local computer (edit with brackets),but failed to run, something I miss? (ignoring the css style here)

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="tools.js"></script>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $document.ready(function(){
                $("#command").keyup(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        submit();
                    }
                });

                var submit = function () {
                    var commandEl = document.getElementById("command");
                    var command = commandEl.value;
                    var outputel = document.getElementById("output");
                    var new_row = document.createElement("div");
                    new_row.innerHTML = "root@host# > " + command;
                    outputel.appendChild(new_row);
                    commandEl.value="";
                };
            })
        </script>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="input">
            root@host# >
            <input type="text" id="command" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: At first glance, you're missing a ; at the end of your JavaScript, and a </body></html>.

Comment: At a glance, I'd say it was `$document.ready`, you need to jQueryize your `document` - make this `$(document).ready` instead.

Comment: <script> tag inside <head>  </head>

Comment: @AdrianWragg Hi,thanks,I forgot to paste it on here.

Comment: Use the new syntax `$(function(){...})`

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann You might want to post that as the answer before it gets drowned out by others.

Comment: @PaulAldred-Bann How can I mark your comment as answer?

Comment: @user1150125 Good news glad it's working, I don't mind missing out on this as it was an easy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use either,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

instead of

```
$document.ready(function(){
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use command function like this,

```
            $("#command").on('keyup', function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    submit();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code (wrong instruction for "document ready" and formatting)

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="tools.js"></script>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
                <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#command").keyup(function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        submit();
                    }
                });

                var submit = function () {
                    var commandEl = document.getElementById("command");
                    var command = commandEl.value;
                    var outputel = document.getElementById("output");
                    var new_row = document.createElement("div");
                    new_row.innerHTML = "root@host# > " + command;
                    outputel.appendChild(new_row);
                    commandEl.value="";
                };
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="input">
            root@host# >
            <input type="text" id="command" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was incorrect around `document.ready()` i.e. `$(document).ready(function(){`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#command").keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                submit();
            }
        });
    });

var submit = function () {
        var commandEl = document.getElementById("command");
        var command = commandEl.value;
        var outputel = document.getElementById("output");
        var new_row = document.createElement("div");
        new_row.innerHTML = "root@host# > " + command;
        outputel.appendChild(new_row);
        commandEl.value="";
    };
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:'Rosario', sans-serif;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #00FF00;
}

#output { margin-bottom: 0px; background-color: #000000; }
#input { margin-top: 0px; background-color: #000000; }

input {
    border: 0;
    background: #000000;
    color: #00FF00;
    outline: none;
    font-family:'Rosario', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: -0.1px;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="input"> 
        root@host# >
        <input type="text" id="command" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```